# Does Divi have a feature to allow users to build a post a from blank page?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, divi-theme

it seems that by default, Divi includes a menu bar on every page. Is there a way to add elements on a blank page, similar to Elementor's "Elementor Canvas" setting? How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, using Divi's 'blank page template' option. For the more recent versions of Divi, this option can be seen when the classic editor is enabled.